# why is chrome payment sheet closed instantly when clicking on rendered Stripe PaymentRequestButtonElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm implementing a payment request button with react and using `@stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js`. My issue is when I click the `pay now` button, the Chrome payment sheet is opened and closed instantly without any error on the console. Please note that I am using `Mac Pro M1` and I am using `ngrok` and I have saved some strip test cards in my Chrome. Below is my code.

GooglePayCheckoutForm.tsx

```
import React, { PureComponent, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Loader } from 'components/common';
import {
  PaymentMethod,
  PaymentRequest, Stripe, StripeElements, StripePaymentRequestButtonElementClickEvent,
} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { ElementsConsumer } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {
  Form, Input, Result,
} from 'antd';
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form';
import { SubscriptionPlans, SubscriptionTypes } from 'core/enums/contract';
import plans from 'core/enums/plans';
import GooglePayBottonElement, { NotAvailableResult } from './GoogleButtonElement';
import styles from '../../styles.module.scss';

type GooglePayCheckoutFormOwnProps = {
  stripe?: Stripe | null;
  elements?: StripeElements | null;
  plan: SubscriptionPlans.PRO | SubscriptionPlans.ENTERPRISE;
  type: SubscriptionTypes;
};

type GooglePayCheckoutFormProps = FormComponentProps & GooglePayCheckoutFormOwnProps;

type GooglePayCheckoutFormStates = {
  canMakePayment: boolean;
  hasCheckedAvailability: boolean;
  paymentMethod: PaymentMethod | null;
  errorMessage: string | null;
  processingGooglePay: boolean;
};

class GooglePayCheckoutForm extends PureComponent<GooglePayCheckoutFormProps, GooglePayCheckoutFormStates> {
    paymentRequest: PaymentRequest;

    constructor(props: GooglePayCheckoutFormProps) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        canMakePayment: false,
        hasCheckedAvailability: false,
        paymentMethod: null,
        errorMessage: null,
        processingGooglePay: true,
      };
    }

    async componentDidUpdate() {
      const { stripe } = this.props;

      if (stripe && !this.paymentRequest) {
        await this.createPaymentRequest(stripe);
      }
    }

    handleGooglePayButton(event:StripePaymentRequestButtonElementClickEvent, paymentMethod:PaymentMethod | null) {
      if (paymentMethod) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          errorMessage:
          'You can only use the PaymentRequest button once. Refresh the page to start over.',
        });
      }
    }

    async createPaymentRequest(stripe: Stripe) {
      const { plan, type } = this.props;
      const selectedPlan = plans.find((item) => item.id === plan);

      if (selectedPlan) {
        this.paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
          
          currency: selectedPlan.currencyAbbreviation,
          total: {
            label: 'total',
            amount: selectedPlan.priceNumber[type],
          },
          country: 'DE',
          disableWallets: ['applePay'],
        });
      
        this.paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', async (event) => {
          this.setState({ paymentMethod: event.paymentMethod });
          event.complete('success');

          // Submiting to server should take place here.
          // this.handleSubmit()
        });
        const canMakePaymentRespose = await this.paymentRequest.canMakePayment();

        if (canMakePaymentRespose) {
          this.setState({ canMakePayment: true, hasCheckedAvailability: true, processingGooglePay: false });
        } else {
          this.setState({ canMakePayment: false, hasCheckedAvailability: true, processingGooglePay: false });
        }
      }
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
      const {
        canMakePayment,
        hasCheckedAvailability,
        errorMessage,
        paymentMethod,
      } = this.state;
      const {
        elements,
        stripe,
        form: { getFieldDecorator },
      } = this.props;

      if (!elements || !stripe) {
        return <Loader loading />;
      }

      return (
        <Loader loading={this.state.processingGooglePay}>
          <Form className={styles.paymentForm}>
            {(!canMakePayment && hasCheckedAvailability && <NotAvailableResult />)}
            {canMakePayment && (
              <>
                <Form.Item label="Coupon Code" colon={false} labelCol={{ xs: 10, sm: 16 }} wrapperCol={{ xs: 14, sm: 8 }}>
                  {getFieldDecorator('coupon')(<Input size="large" placeholder="Enter coupon" />)}
                </Form.Item>
                <GooglePayBottonElement
                  onClickFunction={(event:StripePaymentRequestButtonElementClickEvent) => this.handleGooglePayButton(event, paymentMethod)}
                  paymentRequest={this.paymentRequest as PaymentRequest}
                />
              </>
            )}
            {errorMessage && { errorMessage }}
            {paymentMethod && (
              <Result>
                Got PaymentMethod:
                {' '}
                {paymentMethod.id}
              </Result>
            )}
          </Form>
        </Loader>
      );
    }
}
const WrappedGooglePayCheckoutForm = Form.create<GooglePayCheckoutFormProps>()(GooglePayCheckoutForm);

function InjectedGooglePayCheckoutForm(props: GooglePayCheckoutFormOwnProps) {
  return (
    <ElementsConsumer>
      {({ elements, stripe }) => <WrappedGooglePayCheckoutForm elements={elements} stripe={stripe} {...props} />}
    </ElementsConsumer>
  );
}

export default InjectedGooglePayCheckoutForm;
```

index.tsx

```
import React, { PureComponent, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { SubscriptionPlans, SubscriptionTypes } from 'core/enums/contract';
import { stripeKey } from 'core/constants/env';
import { Stripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js/pure';
import GooglePayCheckoutForm from './GooglePayCheckoutForm';

type Props = {
  plan: SubscriptionPlans.PRO | SubscriptionPlans.ENTERPRISE;
  type: SubscriptionTypes;
};

class GooglePayPayment extends PureComponent<Props> {
  stripePromise: Promise<Stripe | null>;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.stripePromise = loadStripe(stripeKey as string);
  }

  render(): ReactNode {
    const {
      plan,
      type,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Elements stripe={this.stripePromise} key={stripeKey}>
        <GooglePayCheckoutForm
          plan={plan}
          type={type}
        />
      </Elements>
    );
  }
}

export default GooglePayPayment;
```

GoogleButtonElement.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { PaymentRequestButtonElement as StripeGooglePayButtonElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { PaymentRequest, StripePaymentRequestButtonElementClickEvent } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Result } from 'antd';

export function NotAvailableResult() {
  return (
    <Result>
      <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        PaymentRequest is not available in your browser.
      </p>
      {window.location.protocol !== 'https:' && (
        <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          Try using
          {' '}
          <a href="https://ngrok.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            ngrok
          </a>
          {' '}
          to view this demo over https.
        </p>
      )}
    </Result>
  );
}

interface GooglePayButtonElementProps {
  paymentRequest: PaymentRequest,
  onClickFunction:(event: StripePaymentRequestButtonElementClickEvent) => any,
}

function GooglePayButtonElement({ paymentRequest, onClickFunction }:GooglePayButtonElementProps) {
  return (
    <StripeGooglePayButtonElement
      onClick={onClickFunction}
      options={{
        paymentRequest,
        style: {
          paymentRequestButton: {
            type: 'subscribe',
            theme: 'dark',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default GooglePayButtonElement;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod')` handler, You should call [stripe.confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment)  to submit the payment. Sample [code](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?html-or-react=html#html-js-complete-payment) is available in the integration guide.

Also instead of saving a card in Chrome, you need to add an active card to your Google Pay account in order to use Google Pay.

Comment: But in my case, this event is never called. my problem is before that. The Chrome payment sheet is opened and closed automatically in a second. This event will be called after the user selects a card from the payment sheet.